This statement is true or false?
Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. If $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} |f(x)|=\infty$, then $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x)=\infty$ or $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x)=-\infty$. Is this statement true or false?

I have been thinking about this one and I think its false, but im not sure on what the counter example would be. The continuity of the function confuses me. Could you give me a hint please?

Continuity is indeed the point here.  A counterexample would have to be very large (positive) and very large (negative) for some large values of $x$, but it would then have to be $0$ for arbitrarily large $x$.

@Johnstuart First, I do not know the answer. As pointed  out by lulu if  you  relax the restriction that the function must be continuous  then the statement  is false. As written, I believe the statement to be true but I am not sure.

@Bob What is wrong with lulu's comment? Does that not effectively prove it?

@lulu I was thinking of $f(x)=x(-1)^{[x]}$ with $[x]$ floor function, but I think that's not continuous.

To stress:  my initial comment can be turned into a proof.  You just need to sharpen up my sketch.

Suppose $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} |f(x)|=\infty.$ Then $\exists\ c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)\notin [-1,1]\ \forall\ x>c.\ $
Suppose further that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous.
Consider if $f(x)<-1$ for some $x>c,$ and also $f(x')>1$ for some $x'>x.$ By the Intermediate value theorem, $f(x)=0 \in [-1,1]\ $ for some $t\in (x,x'),\ $ contradicting the property of $f$ stated above. We get a similar contradiction for the case where $x>x'$.
Thus we either have $f(x)<-1\ \forall\ x>c,\ $ or $\ f(x)>1\ \forall\ x>c.\ $
But the numbers $-1$ and $1$ here were arbitrary, and all of the above can be repeated for $[-2,2],\ [-3,3],\ $ with different values of $c$ in each case. Then by their definitions, we get that either $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x)=\infty$ or $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x)=-\infty$.
